# With P4V, how to get latest version?

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

My friend and I are using P4V as our version control tool so that we can work on the same project.

We got a problem like :

1. I built the stream depot, and uploaded our project to it;
2. We were working in the same stream called dev, and we got latest version for all files and checked out all of them.
3. I changed a script called A.cs and submitted it successfully.
4. My friend wanted to get the latest version of A.cs that I just modified, but she couldn't. We got this warning //TheAwsome/Main/MakeItCool/Assets/Scripts/A.cs#1 - is opened for edit and cannot be deleted

Some people said that we could use Get Revision with Force Operation to solve this problem. We tried it out, but failed....

Comment: If you ask to get the latest revision, and you have the file open for edit, you have to perform the "resolve" action to merge your edits with the changes in the latest revision. Here's some docs: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Resolving_files.html

Comment: The "cannot be deleted" error suggests that you deleted it rather than editing it.  Does that sound right?

Answer (score 0):

If both of you are pointing to the same depot, but have different workspaces, "p4 sync" should get the latest version of the file. But if the file is open in the workspace then a resolve might be required.